# How do I upload edited files in my SVN repository?

Tags: svn, repository, addition, commit

I am working with a SVN repository. I already have a local copy (i did a checkout). Now I edited some files in that repository and saved them. How do I transfer them to the server. Is it like GIT where I first have to add them to a staging area and then commit them?

Can someone tell me the necessary commands?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf  Read chapter 2 Basic work cycle

Comment: [Commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks! Actually I am just looking for two commands and not the entire 400 pages reference :) SO if you happen to know them, please let me know.

Comment: Anyone? This can't be so hard. I am coming from GIT and there it is not too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

> svn commit -m "your log messages"